# Python Calculator Code not dividing and multiplying correctly

Tags: python

I decided that I wanted to take on a python project to help hone my skills, so I decided to make a python calculator. I was able to get everything up and running, but I am currently running into a problem when I try to multiply or divide through the main function. Right now I have figured out that which ever one comes first it will make the other one do what it is intended to do. For example.. When i try to divide but the multi function is above the div function my divide will turn out multiplied...

I know that there might be some easy way to solve this, but i can't seem to see it! So any help would be much appreciated!

Also any other suggestions to improve my code are welcome!

'''

```
import sys


test = [10, 20]


def add(*arg):
    result = 0
    for x in arg[0]:
        result += x
    print(result)


def sub(*arg):
    arg = arg[0]
    result = arg[0]
    for x in arg[1:]:
        result -= x
    print(result)


def multi(*arg):
    arg = arg[0]
    result = arg[0]
    for x in arg[1:]:
        result *= x
    print(result)


def div(*arg):
    arg = arg[0]
    result = arg[0]
    for x in arg[1:]:
        result /= x
    print(result)


def main():
    while True:
        math_tool = input('What would you like to do:  ').lower()
        if math_tool == 'exit':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            math_choice = \
                list(map(int, input('What would you like to' +
                                    f' {math_tool}: ').split(',')))
            if math_tool == 'add':
                add(math_choice)
            elif math_tool == 'sub':
                sub(math_choice)
            elif math_tool == 'div' or 'divide':
                div(math_choice)
            elif math_tool == 'multi' or 'multiply':
                multi(math_choice)
            else:
                print('error')
    # print(math_choice, '  Type:', type(math_choice[0]))


main()
```

'''

Comment: `math_tool == 'div' or math_tool == 'divide':`. Same with the multi line. `or 'divide'` always evaluates to true.

Comment: @Loocid Thank you for your help! I'm sorry though, what did you mean by 'the multi line' was i missing something on there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a condition just add a condition in `or` you have to check `math_tool` is equal to the string otherwise condition is always true.

```
elif math_tool == 'div' or math_tool == 'divide':
    div(math_choice)
elif math_tool == 'multi' or math_tool == 'multiply':
    multi(math_choice)
```

Comment: also make sure you are using floats since integer divide will produce the wrong result

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was something simple! Thanks for yall's help!

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Thanks, I didn't know about the float and integer thing

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:-

```
num1 = ""
op = ""
num2 = ""

while op != "*" or op != "+" or op != "-" or op != "/":
    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    op = input("Enter operation: ")
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

    if op == "*":
        print("Answer =")
        print(num1 * num2)
        print("\n")
    elif op == "+":
        print("Answer =")
        print(num1 + num2)
        print("\n")
    elif op == "-":
        print("Answer =")
        print(num1 - num2)
        print("\n")
    elif op == "/":
        print("Answer =")
        print(num1 / num2)
        print("\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid Operation")
        print("\n")
```

Comment: Explain why your snippet of code will work and what you have changed.